# Reduce hard drive space taken up by Haystack index

Tags: indexing, django-haystack

How do I minimize the hard drive space taken up by my haystack index? The index takes up more space than the entire database, lol! I am indexing large text portions.

I am thinking of removing all numbers and html tags. But these are just logical things to try, because smaller input = smaller output. But I think I am missing something fundamental in the way haystack works, and the reason the index becomes larger than the database itself.

In my index template I have a number of text and date fields.

EDIT: Below are samples of my index creation file and template. Let me know if I am doing something wrong or inefficient. All of the fields are searchable.

search_indexes.py:

```
class MainIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    pnum = indexes.CharField(null=True)
    anum = indexes.CharField(model_attr='anum', null=True)
    ititle = indexes.CharField(model_attr='ititle', null=True)
    de = indexes.CharField(null=True)
    cs = indexes.CharField(null=True)
    ab = indexes.CharField(null=True)
    in = indexes.CharField(null=True)
    as = indexes.CharField(null=True)
    pt = indexes.CharField(null=True)
```

main_text.text:

```
{{ object.pnum }}
{{ object.anum }}
{{ object.de }}
{{ object.cs }}
{{ object.ab }}
{{ object.in }}
{{ object.as }}
{{ object.ititle }}
{{ object.ps}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The benefit from any index is that it prevents excessive processing queries, so indexes can pre-processed, the results from this are meta-information in the shape of maps and trees pointing to the real data to simplify the query work.

You should have indexes only on data that is searchable.

Comment: Please take a look at my index and template excerpts above and let me know if you have additional comments. I realize the question was vague but really your answer says only the obvious, while I need specific guidance. Please assist